# NIC not recognized after installation

Tags: network-interface

I've got a strange problem recognizing a network adapter on a computer. Computer has 6 network ports, and one of them is not working properly in Oracle Linux 8. I havent't tried other OSes, because I need to run Oracle Linux on that computer.

When I start the OS installation all 6 network adapters are shown in installation network settings, and all interfaces work. When OS is installed one adapter (`enp0s25`) is missing.

Here is the `lscpi -vvv` output for that adapter:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0000
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 20
    Region 0: Memory at c1600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Region 1: Memory at c162e000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Region 2: I/O ports at 8080 [size=32]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=1 PME-
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee00338  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
        AFCap: TP+ FLR+
        AFCtrl: FLR-
        AFStatus: TP-
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

`ip address` outputs:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:01:c0:31:49:20 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:01:c0:31:48:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:01:c0:30:53:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: enp6s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:01:c0:31:49:17 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: enp8s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:01:c0:31:49:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:6b:dd:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:6b:dd:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Similarly, `nmcli device show` does not show `enp0s25`.

If I plug in a cable to that adapter, the light shows that the link is established on hardware level. Searching for `ens0p25` in `/var/log` show the results only in `/var/log/anaconda` directory, which proves that the adapter works during installation, and not after the OS is installed.

I've got another batch of `identical` computers which are obviously different generation. That computers have `I218-LM (rev 04)` instead of `rev 03` network adapter on 00:19.0. For that one `enp0s25` adapter works flawlessly.

My suspicion tells me that there is a problem with e1000e driver, but I am confused why does the adapter work during installation process. What is the difference between the driver used during installation and the driver installed in OS? Can I somehow port the driver from the installation process to the OS driver? I am using completely automated installation, and would not like to compile a driver manually. However, If I find a solution with another driver, I might be forced to do that. Anything to get this NIC working.

I was also thinking about trying to update firmware on that adapter, but I am not sure it would help, and I don't know yet if I can do that. I only found some info how to upload boot firmware for wake on lan.

---

**Additional information:** I installed Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 to see if there is something different. Interestingly and unfortunately, the problem is identical. I can press "Try Ubuntu" when it is booted from installation USB drive. `enp0s25` is present there and working during installation. Then I install Ubuntu 22.04 on computer, and after the boot into installed system the network adapter is no longer available. Outputs of the commands lspci, nmcli, ip are identical. Ubuntu 22.04.1 uses 5.15 kernel, while there is 4.18 in Oracle Linux 8.1.

---

**Another update:** CentOS7 installation shows the opposite behaviour. During installation the network card is not detected. After the CentOS7 is installed the network adapter is present in the system and works.

Computers are Compulab IPC2 with 6 ethernet adapters. Clearly, we have two different generations of the same computer model.

The working model lspci outputs:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI KT (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8603 3-lane, 3-Port PCI Express Gen 2 (5.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ab)
06:01.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8603 3-lane, 3-Port PCI Express Gen 2 (5.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ab)
06:02.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8603 3-lane, 3-Port PCI Express Gen 2 (5.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ab)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
```

The non working model lspci outputs:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 6000 (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
04:00.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8603 3-lane, 3-Port PCI Express Gen 2 (5.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ab)
05:01.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8603 3-lane, 3-Port PCI Express Gen 2 (5.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ab)
05:02.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8603 3-lane, 3-Port PCI Express Gen 2 (5.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ab)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
```

`dmesg` resports nothing about `enp0s25`. It just reports for all other adapters (sample just for enp1s0):

```
igb 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: renamed from eth0
...
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0: link is not ready
...
```

Comment: As suspected, it seems that this is a hardware fault. Windows also report faulty adapter, and it does not work there either. I am sending computers back to be repaired.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the 6 adapters of the same type? Are they all integrated to the system motherboard or are some of them on add-on cards?

Can you see any messages related to the missing NIC in `dmesg` output?

Have you checked if there is a difference between a reboot (like one at the end of OS installation) and a real power-off/power-on cycle? If the system has remote management features, and they are enabled, you might even have to physically unplug the system to really power down the NIC that is integrated to the management features.

The I218-LM is capable of being connected to the system chipset's Manageability Engine (ME for short), if the chipset has one. If all the NICs in the system are the same type, and only one has this problem, is the problematic NIC the one that has ME connectivity associated with it? In other words, does the problem port have any "remote console" or "remote management" functionality associated with it, and the others don't? If the answer is yes, the reason might be the ME interfering with the use of the NIC.

[The latest stable version of the driver source code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/ich8lan.c?h=v5.19.3) indicates that if ME is present and connected to the NIC, it will have the responsibility of switching in and out of Ultra-Low Power mode, and the driver includes precautions for a ME firmware bug that might cause delays in NIC configuration. So, if this is a motherboard-integrated NIC, a BIOS/ME firmware update might help.

Also, if you have disabled the Intel ME drivers in your OS setup, perhaps as part of some system hardening effort during your automated installation, that might block the communication between the ME and the NIC driver that is necessary in Ultra-Low Power mode switching with ME-connected NICs.

The PXE boot firmware should not be related to this issue, but it should not hurt to upgrade it if you wish to try. However, on motherboard-integrated NICs, the PXE boot firmware is often integrated to the system BIOS and is upgraded as part of the BIOS upgrade process, not as a separate firmware item. In my experience, the Intel PXE boot firmware upgrade tools will only work with add-on cards that have their own stand-alone boot firmware.

Because of the possible ME connection, it might be important to know your system model. If you can disclose it, please *add the information into your original question*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The I218LM is the only adapter of that type in the computer. The computer is Compulab IPC2 with version with 6 ethernet adapters. I will update the question with lspci output of two generations of IPC2 we have. One is working fine while other is not.

Comment: There is additional information in the question.